# Cannot access memory at address?

Tags: c, gdb

I observed a strange behavior from gdb. Please assist me to identify this. 
Below is affected snippet.
Note: Below for loop should not execute more than two times as max value of totNumEntries is 2.

```
totNumEntries = callLegPtr->activeSpContextPtr->directMediaPtr->numEntries;
        for (index = 0; index < totNumEntries; index++)
        {
        ....... 
        }
```

Printing values via gdb:

```
(gdb) p index
$79 = 35933
(gdb) p totNumEntries
$80 = 65535
(gdb) p callLegPtr->activeSpContextPtr->directMediaPtr->numEntries
Cannot access memory at address 0x53369955
```

As per gdb print, 0x53369955 is out of bond and cannot be accessible but still i can see "totNumEntries" having value 65535 because of that reason above for loop went into to many iterations (35933) and our process declared time out. 
Type of  totNumEntries is unsigned short (Max value is 65535).

My concern is what exactly the meaning of "Cannot access memory at address 0x53369955". When 0x53369955 is not accessible  how come "totNumEntries" taking large value which maximum range for unsigned int type. It is very important for me to understand, please let me know if you need any further information.

Regards,
Shahid Hussain

Comment: Why do you expect a sensible result from reading out of bound memory? Anyways, please post a [mcve].

Comment: There's a defect in your code. Only you can see the code. Only you can identify the defect.

Comment: On which line is your breakpoint ? Or on which line did your program segfault ? I suppose it's on `totNumEntries = callLegPtr->activeSpContextPtr->directMediaPtr->numEntries;`

Comment: totally depends on what you are doing inside the `for` loop. You need to see why `index` is printed with value 35933.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: there is no segmentation fault is observed here. It is manual core dump. Since above for loop was taking too much time so our timeout handler did the manual core dump (Product specific logic).

Comment: @BaummitAugen David: Actually reason why "callLegPtr->activeSpContextPtr->directMediaPtr->numEntries" is pointing to that address is still under investigation. My first concern is when i m assigning value from "callLegPtr->activeSpContextPtr->directMediaPtr->numEntries" to "totNumEntries " it is not giving any error and 65535 is being assigned to "totNumEntries ".

Comment: 'our timeout handler did the manual core dump' - so, essentially, the problem occurred a billion cycles ago when 'callLegPtr->activeSpContextPtr->directMediaPtr->numEntries' was pointing at the wrong, but reachable, address.  By the time gdb got at your thread, it was no longer reachable.  Maybe it has been freed or otherwise deallocated by that time.